# Multidimensional array output as JSON

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do something I'm not entirely sure is possible.

I start with a database similar to this:

```
create table events (id int primary key, common int, location text);

insert into events values (2, 100, 'Something');
insert into events values (3, 100, 'Something');
insert into events values (4, 100, 'Something');
insert into events values (5, 200, 'Something');
insert into events values (6, 200, 'Something');
insert into events values (7, 200, 'Something');
insert into events values (8, 200, 'Something');
insert into events values (9, 100, 'Something');
insert into events values (10, 200, 'Something');
insert into events values (11, 200, 'Something');
insert into events values (12, 200, 'Something');
insert into events values (13, 300, 'Something');
insert into events values (14, 200, 'Something');
insert into events values (15, 300, 'Something');
insert into events values (16, 200, 'Something');
insert into events values (17, 300, 'Something');
```

And I want to get data grouped into an object with `common` values as keys:

```
{
  "100":{
    "2":"Something",
    "3":"Something",
    "4":"Something",
    "9":"Something"},
  "200":{
    "5":"Something",
    "6":"Something",
    "7":"Something",
    "8":"Something"},
  "300":{
    "13":"Something",
    "15":"Something",
    "17":"Something",
    "18":"Something"}
}
```

I can, of course, do it with multiple selects, but a single select would be beneficial.

Any help would be fantastic! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For PostgreSQL of any version**

The important part here is the correct `SELECT` that would group your data in such a way to make it easy to transform into your dictionary type:

```
SELECT * FROM events GROUP BY common, id ORDER BY common
```

It produces the following output:

```
2    100    "Something"
3    100    "Something"
4    100    "Something"
9    100    "Something"
5    200    "Something"
6    200    "Something"
7    200    "Something"
8    200    "Something"
10   200    "Something"
11   200    "Something"
12   200    "Something"
14   200    "Something"
16   200    "Something"
13   300    "Something"
15   300    "Something"
17   300    "Something"
```

At this point, no matter what language you use for your server-side code, transforming it into a dictionary with `common` as the keys becomes an easy task.

For example, in Node.js you can do it like this:

```
function transform(rows) {
    var key, obj, result = {};
    rows.forEach(function (r) {
        if (r.common !== key) {
            if (obj) {
                result[key] = obj;
            }
            obj = {};
            key = r.common;
        }
        obj[r.id] = r.location;
    });
    if (obj) {
        result[key] = obj;
    }
    return result;
}
```

For a complete example, using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM events GROUP BY common, id ORDER BY common')
    .then(data=> {
        console.log(transform(data));
    })
    .catch(error=> {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Outputs:

```
{
    '100': {
        '2': 'Something',
        '3': 'Something',
        '4': 'Something',
        '9': 'Something'
    },
    '200': {
        '5': 'Something',
        '6': 'Something',
        '7': 'Something',
        '8': 'Something',
        '10': 'Something',
        '11': 'Something',
        '12': 'Something',
        '14': 'Something',
        '16': 'Something'
    },
    '300': {
        '13': 'Something',
        '15': 'Something',
        '17': 'Something'
    }
}
```

**For PostgreSQL 9.4 and later**

With PostgreSQL 9.4 and later you can do it all in SQL, using function `json_object_agg`:

```
SELECT json_object_agg(common, j ORDER BY common)
FROM (SELECT common, json_object_agg(id, location order by id)
AS j FROM events GROUP BY common) t;
```

**Performance Comparison**

Comparing the performance of the standard vs the new approach isn't easy, but consider this:

We have a simple single select + a very simple and fast transformation, versus a dual select + dual aggregation on the server. Therefore, I wouldn't be surprised if the older solution outperformed the new one.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking this would be the best way to do it, thanks for the code :D I'm doing it in PHP so the code isn't what I'm after but I'm pretty sure I can translate it. Thanks!